# Is it possible to invoke a function in VBA from java?

Tags: java, ms-access, vba

I have two programs running on my computer, one designed and implemented in Java, the other one implemented as an .mdb-file. Can i invoke an simple function in my Access-program from the Java-program?

Comment: This Link might help you
http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thank you for the tip, unfortunately this library only allows you to work with the tables in access, i want to run functions programmed in access-forms.